# How to get a good resolution Image from google earth and use it in Arcmap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, google-earth, resolution

I need to make an orthophoto from google-earth. My orthophoto covers a large area and whenever I save the image in google-earth and put it in the Arcmap to rectify it , the image has very large resolution. I have found a software called "Google Satellite Maps Downloader" (which is not free). This software takes images for smaller areas from google-earth and stick them together, providing an ortho photo with better resolution. Unfortunately  my orthophoto is for a big area and the image which I get from the free version of this software  still has a bad quality. I was wondering if there is another way to get high quality satellite image from google-earth?

Comment: Other post is correct - what your are trying to do probably isn't legal. You can connect to ESRI resources that provide satellite image background that is a bit closer to legal - depends on what you do with the work product.

Answer (score 2):

The Answer is that you don't do something like this.

Firstly, the data in Google Earth, isn't raw, and has been processed in a variety of ways, and can have locational and radiometric problems.

Secondly, and more importantly, the Terms and Conditions of Google Earth, prohibit the usage of data in such a way.

You are better off either purchasing such data from commercial vendors, or finding it from local government or other such similar places.